# Magento Order and Product pagination

Tags: magento, pagination, magento2

i want to know how we can identify the number of page are there in particular store while sync the product or order from magento store, when we integrate our web-app with magento

if we call the get all product using post-man in the response how we can identify there is more page are on that store and how we can find the next page url or something

i am trying to set the customer parameter like current page and last page in request but this is thing is static what i want is when i am request for all product i want to know how many pages are there so i can send request that many times